# Providing translations for R Bookdown project

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Am currently working on a rewrite of a LaTeX project into R Markdown, which has had some people interested in translating it to a multitude of languages.

The project is written in [bookdown](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/), but can't seem to find anything in the documentation pointing me in the right direction.

It will build the website and requisite files using Gitlab CI after someone makes a change. What is the best way to add other languages to the project?

Comment: See if [this latex package](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/translator/translator.pdf) is along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you provide an example book code (preferably via github repo) to test on?

Comment: However,  you may find this [`babelquarto`](https://github.com/ropensci-review-tools/babelquarto) package helpful.